# Can I completely disable 'debugger' in scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools, ie-developer-tools

I wanted to see the network log of a third-party web site. (No malicious purposes, just to solve a login problem of a client who is a legitimate user of the web site.) But it seems the developers have put some measure to prevent that. Some dynamically generated function loops 200 times and calls `debugger`. So, if I open the developer tool, it constantly stops and "Never pause here" does not work either, because its location keeps changing.

I tried all major browsers (Chrome, FF, Edge) and they all stopped. Is there any way temporarily to disable all `debugger` pause, or a web browser that has a developer tool but ignores that keyword?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome's dev tools has a Disable All Breakpoints button which will ignore this.

Comment: Where is that button? Is that the horizontal bookmark-like icon? I had tried to clicked that, but the browser and developer tool was unresponsive, so I thought it was not the solution. But it seems that I was wrong. The browser & tool is just very unresponsive with high CPU usage. It is unresponsive, but I think I can manage to test it... with patience. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @DamnVegetables In the "Sources" tab, top right button that has a slash through a right-pointing arrow; hover text is "Disable breakpoints". I just did a quick test in a fiddle and it did not break on the `debugger` keyword.

Comment: Yes, that. After pressing it, the browser/tool became very unresponsive, and after a while, the developer tool showed "aw snap!".

Comment: @DamnVegetables that's because it's a busy loop. If the `debugger` call doesn't stop, it still keeps pushing into the call stack until it overflows and crashes.

Comment: If anyone has a way of achieving this in Waterfox Classic (based on Firefox 56), let us know. (I Know we shouldn't be using browsers based on outdated versions, but for many things, a lot of us still do, FWIW)

Answer (score 0):

In IE and Edge you can detach the debugger using the "Disconnect debugger" toggle. It's the 2nd icon from the left of the debugger's command bar. When disconnected the debugger will ignore all break reasons. I'd open the tools somewhere else, disconnect, and then  navigate to the page you wanted to look at.

[image]